# Problema con CHARSET en SQLServer con odbc PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2012

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Cuando hago un insert con una query pura a la base de datos de la siguiente cadena:

`áÁúÚÑñÁ`

no tengo ningún problema, lo inserta bien. Lo aclaro para ya descartar un problema con la base de datos
El problema sucede cuando se ejecuta la consulta utilizando estas funciones:

**1)** Acá preparo la consulta SQL haciendo un bind. Ejemplo: `INSERT INTO ip_ideas(id_usuario ,content) VALUES (?,?)`

```php
public function store($table, $params)
    {
        try {
            $this->connect();
            $count = count($params);
            $strKeys = "(" . implode(" ,", array_keys($params)) . ")";
            $strVals = "(?" . str_repeat(",?", $count - 1) . ")";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table$strKeys VALUES " . $strVals;
            $query = $this->prepare($sql);
            return $this->executeQuery($query, $params, true);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $th;
        }
    }
```

En esta función, el arreglo de parámetros, `$params`, sigue estando con los valores correctos, ahora muestro el método `executeQuery($query, $params, true);`

**2)** Acá recibo la `query` del método store (mostrado anteriormente), y un arreglo de los parámetros, la ejecución de la query se da en `$ret = odbc_execute($stmt, $parameters);`

```php
function executeQuery($stmt, $parameters, $alta = false)
    {
        odbc_exec($this->conn, "SET NOCOUNT ON");
        $ret = odbc_execute($stmt, $parameters);
        if ($alta) {
            $r = odbc_exec($this->conn, "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID");
            odbc_fetch_into($r, $row);
            $ret = $row[0];
        }
        return $ret;
    }
```

Cuando ejecuta la linea `$ret = odbc_execute($stmt, $parameters);` **acá es donde "dispara" el problema**, inserta mal la cadena

Pero esto sucede solo cuando utilizo esta secuencia de  ejecución para insertar, si yo ejecuto una query pura con así: `odbc_exec(CONNECTION, $query);` no sucede el problema

pasa de `áÁúÚÑñÁ` a esto `Ã¡Ã?ÃºÃsÃ'Ã±Ã?`
me di cuenta que el problema sucede únicamente cuando hay una mayúscula con tilde, no sucede si inserto solo minúsculas con tilde.

Ya se me agotaron los recursos, no encuentre mucha solución en internet.
Espero que me puedan ayudar. Desde ya muchas gracias. Saludos

**SOLUCION**

Tengo la siguiente función que la utilizo para solucionar otros problemas relacionados, pero sin tocar base de datos, estaba tratando de solucionarlo con esto, antes de llamar el método `executeQuery` (descripto arriba), pasaba el arreglo de de los parámetros por la función y el elemento "convertido" ahí llegaba a `executeQuery`, pero no lograba un resultado positivo

```php
function deutf8ize($param)
{
    if (is_array($param)) {
        foreach ($param as $unaKey => $unValor) {
            $param[$unaKey] = deutf8ize($unValor);
        }
    } else if (is_string($param)) {
        if (mb_detect_encoding($param, "UTF-8", true)) {
            $param = utf8_decode($param);
        }
        return $param;
    }
    return $param;
}
```

Pero sucede algo raro que me hace desconocer un poco el lenguaje, si yo ejecuto la función descripta arriba, dentro de scope del método `executeQuery` ahí **funciona** todo perfectamente, es como si al pasar el elemento por parámetros (viajando de función en función), hace que "pierda el efecto" el `utf8_decode`

Realice una traza de ejecución desde que me ingresa el string hasta que inserta en la base de datos, y no detecto ninguna alteración a nivel código

ahora me quedo así el método `executeQuery`, de esta forma logro el resultado deseado

```php
function executeQuery($stmt, $parameters, $alta = false)
    {
        $parameters = deutf8ize($parameters);
        odbc_exec($this->conn, "SET NOCOUNT ON");
        $ret = odbc_execute($stmt, $parameters);
        if ($alta) {
            $r = odbc_exec($this->conn, "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID");
            odbc_fetch_into($r, $row);
            $ret = $row[0];
        }
        return $ret;
    }
```

Mi problema quedo resuelto. Me queda esa duda de comportamiento.

Muchas gracias Saludos

Comment: debería haber una forma de decirle al servidor el encoding del cliente ( en mysql es trivial con un `SET client_encoding=` ) , o enviar los datos ya codificados con [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.iconv.php) para ver los posibles encodings del alfabeto latino https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_%28computing%29

Comment: Perdon mi ignrancia, pero no entiendo si yo ya recibo en el servidor (backend php) el string de forma correcta `áÁúÚÑñÁ` pero porque cuando lo inserto haciendo un bind de los parametros me lo inserta asi `Ã¡Ã?ÃºÃsÃ'Ã±Ã?` ?

Comment: Ejecutando mb_detect_encoding($string, "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1,WINDOWS-1252"); me devuelve UTF-8 y el charset en el string de conexion esta en UTF-8

Comment: pareciera q la cosa está en [`Elements of this array will be converted to strings by calling this function.`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php) esa conversión estaría fallando. tirale un set explicito para los charset que a veces las conexiones se resetean a defaults ( aunque eso era mas de php 5.x ) sino un iconv en el array params mientras encontras si hay algun flag o config que te esta afectando esa conversión ( mbstring, locales, etc)

Comment: Ahi Edite la pregunte con una solución que logre, pero también describo un comportamiento raro de php con respecto a pasar elementos por parámetros, espero que se entienda cualquier cosa lo edito

Comment: sospecho que está relacionado con los locales, si te interesa reformula la pregunta o crea una nueva especificando sistema operativo ( versión ) versión de php y servidor web/http con un ejemplo de cadenas que cambian, btw [`utf8_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) tiene un aviso de `DEPRECATED` en php 8.2